# SQL login/logout table

Tags: sql

We have a table that tracks users logging in and out.

This query returns all records in order of the last action first etc:

```
SELECT  [entryid]
      ,[index]
      ,[sessionid]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[UserPublicIP]
      ,[EntryDateTime]
      ,[ServerIP]
      ,[EventDesc]
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[table]
  order by EntryDateTime desc
```

We need a query to return the current users logged in.

The possible values for: EventDesc are:

```
Session Login Succeeded
Session Logoff Succeeded
Session reconnection succeeded
Session has been disconnected
Shell start notification received
etc
```

How can we create q SQL query that lists the Username's (& other columns) from the rows that the last EntryDesc was: Session Login Succeeded or Session reconnection succeeded ie user logged in.

We have tried using Distinct & Group By query's such as the below but they do not seem to work:

```
Select * From [DB].[dbo].[table] Group By Username
Select Distinct Username From [DB].[dbo].[table]
```

FYI: A row is created in the table each time a user log's in our etc and so the query needs to select the latest row for the username in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the last record for each user before a given date.  From your syntax, I'm going to guess that you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can do this with `row_number()`.  The following query gets that last row before a given date:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Username order by EntryDatetime desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where EntryDatetime < @Datetime
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

To aggregate this and get a count:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Username order by EntryDatetime desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where EntryDatetime < @Datetime  -- <-- remove this for the most recent entries
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and 
      EntryDesc in ('Session Login Succeeded', 'Session reconnection succeeded');
```

You can remove the inner `where` clause if you want the most recent entry in the database.